# Best method to redirect internal DNS to external website?

Tags: redirect, web-hosting, internal-dns, intranet

We host several web based applications outside of intranet.  The URL's to these applications are long, complex and overall not user friendly.  Ex:

```
http://hostingsite:port/approot/folder/folder/login.aspx <-- (production)
http://hostingsite:port22/approot/folder/folder/login.aspx <-- (dev)
http://hostingsite:port33/approot/folder/folder/login.aspx <-- (test)
```

I'd like to create an internal DNS entry to allow users to access these sites with ease.  Ex:

```
http://prod  --> http://hostingsite:port/approot/folder/folder/login.aspx
http://dev --> http://hostingsite:port22/approot/folder/folder/login.aspx
```

I'm not familiar with the DNS process and setup, as far as I know a DNS can only be redirected to an IP, but not to subdomains for directory paths as described above?  Is this a correct assumption?

I am thinking for throwing up an internal webserver that will listen to the internal DNS entries and redirect to the external sites.

```
http://prod --> [internal webserver] --> redirect --> http://hostingsite:port/approot/folder/folder/login.aspx
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. DNS can only resolve the domain part but is unaware of any kind of path structure. Therefore the esiest solution would be a webserver to redirect or reverse proxy, like you proposed.